# MySQL/jenkins/monit unable to bind to ports

Tags: networking

I am running a dedicated linux server and nothing but apache can bind to ports! This included mysql, jenkins and monit. This is very confusing. I cannot see any conflicting bindings in netstat. This was working before I restarted!

EDIT: netstat -ltn gives:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: What error are the applications giving when they fail to bind?

Comment: @ShaneMadden MySQL: `131229 19:10:25 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address
131229 19:10:25 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?` Jenkins: `Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address` I have to go to sleep now (GMT) so I will be unavailable till the morning.

Comment: Look at your network configuration. Also, why on earth do you have Samba and a printer server on here?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @michael-hampton who asked me to check my network configuration, it is all working now. I had changed networks and so changed IP's! The services were trying to bind to the old IP not the new one.